# tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: placed in category is not called for UITableViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, ios5, objective-c-category

I have an `UITableViewController`

```
@interface GenderSelectController : UITableViewController

- (id)initWithPreviousGender:(NSString*)prevGender;

@end

@implementation GenderSelectController

- (id)initWithPreviousGender:(NSString *)_prevGender
{
    // It's not loaded from nib but created in code
    if ((self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped])) {
        prevGender = _prevGender;
    }
    return self;
}
```

And I have a category method

```objective-c
@interface UITableViewController (RowHeight)

@end

@implementation UITableViewController (RowHeight) 

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return (indexPath.row) ? tableView.rowHeight : tableView.rowHeight - 1;
}

@end
```

And it's NOT called until I do it explicitely

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return [super tableView:tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

But another category, for `UIViewController` which implements `UITableViewDelegate` method, it working just fine. What's the matter?

Comment: you're adding a new method to UITableViewController by the category. heightForRowAtIndexPath is a delegate method of UITableViewDelegate protocol. It won't be called unless the UITableView's delegate is set to itself, or you call it explicitly as you do in the last snippet

Comment: So why it's automatically called for `UIViewController` which conforms to the `UITableViewDelegate` protocol and not called for `UITableViewController` even if I writing `self.tableView.delegate = self`?

Comment: perhaps you have the connection established in InterfaceBuilder? Btw. from my experience it's better to avoid UITableViewController entirely, it only creates problems like with initialization from xibs etc.

Comment: In this controller there are no XIB) So why I'm creating these crazy categories: in my cell I have a custom separator at the top and the bottom of the background image and between 1st and 2nd rows border is duplicated! It's all because the first row is 1 px taller than others! And now I don't want to make a bunch of interfaces and use `UIViewController`.